# C++ strftime() incorrect output

Tags: c++, datetime, strftime

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char dateStringBuffer[256] = "";
    tm date;

    date.tm_year = 2017;
    date.tm_mon = 9;
    date.tm_mday = 13;

    strftime(dateStringBuffer, 256, "%d.%m.%Y", &date);
    cout << dateStringBuffer;
}
```

The output is:

> 13.10.3917

Expected output:

> 13.09.2017

It makes no sense to me. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Probably I only read the "day of the month – [1, 31] " and I assumed the others to be logical like this.

Comment: If you insist on something logical, best not go with a decades old design for C.  [Here is something modern](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) and it goes like this: `cout << format("%d.%m.%Y\n", 2017_y/9/13);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `struct tm` in `corecrt_wtime.h` has the following comments next to it's members.

```
int tm_mon;   // months since January - [0, 11]
int tm_year;  // years since 1900
```

which means that you should have done something of this sort :

```
date.tm_year = 117;
date.tm_mon = 8;
date.tm_mday = 13;
```

This would give you your expected output of : `13.09.2017`

Answer (score 1):

`std::tm`'s members don't all take raw date values, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm

`tm_myear` is the years since 1900 and `tm_mon` uses 0 for January

Answer (score 1):

The `tm_year` is the number of years after 1900.
The `tm_mon` is the month within the year where January corresponds with `0`.